# How to maximize apps to fullscreen on secondary display while using two screens in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, kodi

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. My long distance gf and I have started watching TV whilst video chatting with hangouts. My goal is to have Kodi on full screen on my large external monitor whilst I have hangouts open on full screen on my laptop's display. At the moment however, as soon as I maximize Kodi to full screen it goes into full screen on my laptop's display by default, and the only way of getting it full screen on my monitor is by turning off my laptop's display which defeats the point of what I'm trying to achieve in the first place. My solution atm is to maximize it but not put it into full screen, but this means I can see the launcher and the video for whatever reason is bit more choppy than it should be (this might be due to memory constraints mind you).

Does anyone know of a fix? Some way to override the default of Kodi going into full screen on my laptop rather than my monitor? Is there some way to perhaps temporarily assign the monitor the status of primary display?